# Swapping the integrand and variables being integrated

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I am reading a paper in which the following integral is solved, but I am not sure how to derive the answer myself.  The integral is:

$$\int_{F_{x-1}}^{F_x} du {\int_{G_{y-1}}^{G_y}{dv}\  C^*(u,v)} \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  [1] $$

I know that the answer simplifies to:
$$ \frac{f_X g_Y}{4} * \{ C^*(F_{X}, G_{Y}) + C^*(F_{X}, G_{Y-1}) + C^*(F_{X-1}, G_{Y}) + C^*(F_{X-1}, G_{Y-1}) \} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [2]$$

The original integral is, 
$$\int_{F_{x-1}}^{F_x}{\int_{G_{y-1}}^{G_y}{C^*(u,v)}\ du\ dv } \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  [3] $$
which I think is supposed to be the same as Equation [1].

What I do know for a fact is the following:
$$\int_{F_{x-1}}^{F_x} du {\int_{G_{y-1}}^{G_y}{dv}} = (F(x)-F(x-1))\times(G(y)-G(y-1)) = f_X g_Y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [4]$$

From Equation [4], I can kind of see where the answer is coming from, but obviously I cannot just pull out $C^*(u,v)$ from the integral itself?  I am beginning to think that the author rewrote Equation [3] in the form of Equation [1] deliberately, but I am unsure as to why?  It seems that the function to be integrated, $C^*(u,v)$ is swapped with the variables to be integrated but I haven't seen this form of an integral before, so I'm not 100% sure what I'm working with.

Something else that I tried is the following:
$$ \int^2_1 x dx = 2 - 1/2 = 3/2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [5]$$
$$ \int^2_1 dx\  x =  \frac{x|^2_1 * (1 + 2)}{2} = 3/2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [6]$$
But really, I'm not sure where the divide by 2 (I just put it in there to make the answers equal) in Equation 6 comes from, or whether I just got lucky somehow and this is not a rule in general?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Edit #1:

All, so I investigated the simple example that I tried further and I think I have a solution.  Generalizing Equation's 5 and 6, what I want to see is when the following is true:
$$ \int_a^b{f(x)dx} = F(b)-F(a) \stackrel{?}{=} \int_a^b{dx\ f(x)} = \frac{(b-a)*(f(a)+f(b))}{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [7] $$
Lets have a look at this geometrically ...

[image: Image 1]

The blue line represents a general function $f(x)$.  What we see here is the black hatched area represents the value of $\int_a^b{f(x) dx}$ while the red hatched area represents the value of $\frac{(b-a)(f(a)+f(b))}{2}$.  So now from this, lets think about when these two values will be equal.  For this, refer to Figure 2 below.

[image: Image 2]

We can see that the red-hatched area and the black-hatched area will be equal if the areas of the orange triangle's are equivalent.  This means that the LHS and RHS of Equation 7 are equivalent if that condition holds true.  I think that means that we can say in general that Equation 7 is true if the function being integrated is linear in the region of integration.  If the function is not linear in the region of integration, then if the area's (not necessarily traingular any longer) are equivalent then Equation 7 still holds.  I think the derivation then for Equation [2] is a 2-D extension of this principle.  Anybody have thoughts on this?

Comment: What is the nature of $C^\ast$ ?

Comment: $C^*$ is in general an increasing linear piece-wise function that is continuous.  I will need to double check in order for my Edit #1 to be relevant, but I think that over the region of integration it is just a linear increasing function, and not piece-wise in the limits of integration.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. In literally every piece of literature I've read there is no difference between the two expressions.

Comment: @avid19, which expressions (can you specify equation numbers?) are you referring to?  I agree that in general, Equation 1 is the same as Equation 3.  However, I was trying to understand how to derive Equation 2, and you'll notice in Equation 2 that the answer of the integral is still in terms of $C^*$, not the integral of $C^*$ which we can denote as $C'$.